# How create table with aws glue with indexes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Consider a snippet:

```
glueContext.getSinkWithFormat(
  connectionType = "postgresql",
  options = JsonOptions(Map(
    "url" -> "jdbc://myurl",
    "dbtable" -> "myTable",
    "user" -> "user",
    "password" -> "password"
  ))
).writeDynamicFrame(frame)
```

This creates table if not exists automatically, but without any idexes or id columns. Is there a way to setup a glue to
create them?